# Magento2 - Order collection, How to get billing address?

Tags: magento2, collection

I have below code.

```
$collection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
                //['increment_id', 'global_currency_code', 'status', 'updated_at']
                ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => [
                    Order::STATE_CLOSED,
                    Order::STATE_COMPLETE,
                    Order::STATE_CANCELED
                ]])
                ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['from' => $result['from'], 'to' => $result['to']]);

            $data = $collection->getData();
```

How can I get billing address in my collection?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
foreach ($collection as $order) {
   $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
}
```

Please, always check magento core firstly, mostly your answers to your questions lies there.

Comment: I want to get all the data in one request, I have about 50,000 products and I don't really want to run a loop

Comment: By reading your code, you are already asking for a loop because you are forming a collection. If you want to get a single order - use a order repository or create a search criteria with conditions to fit a single order. By you example you are fetching multiple entities, but somehow you want to get billing address of all of those entities at the same time without loop in a single call - that is not possible without a loop.